# How to bulk download files in Powershell with URLs that have two variable numbers?

Tags: powershell, download, range, bulk

I need to download a large number (hundreds of thousands) of files from the website http://www.siaapm.cultura.mg.gov.br/acervo/memorial_imprensa/, and the URL pattern is http://www.siaapm.cultura.mg.gov.br/acervo/memorial_imprensa/1/1.jpg. Therefore, I need a bulk solution that comprises two number ranges: folder and file. How can it be done in Windows PowerShell?

So far, here's what I've tried:

```
$edicao = [0-100000]
$pagina = [0-300000]
$url = "http://www.siaapm.cultura.mg.gov.br/acervo/memorial_imprensa/$edicao/$pagina.jpg"
$output = "C:\APM\$edicao-$pagina.jpg"
Import-Module BitsTransfer
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output
```

All solutions I found so far dealt with variations only in the filename, not the folder as well.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to post what I've tried so far so I can get proper help. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `$edicao = 0..100000`. This will make an array containing the range from 0 through 100000. Change your first two lines to that layout. Next issue is doing some Foreach-Object looping to iterate through each case:

```
$edicao | Foreach-Object {
    #do work
}
```